# Finding the second fundamental form of a surface in four dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

How can I find the second fundamental form of an equatorial 2-sphere embedded into a 3-sphere?

Firstly, I have tried to build two normal vectors (I got only one of them) however I have not succeed yet. I wanted to work them out by solving a system of dot products equal to zero.

The original task is as stated: prove that the equatorial 2-sphere in a 3-sphere is a minimal surface.

Comment: While the position vector field is normal to $\Bbb S^2$, it is not tangent to $\Bbb S^3$, so that's no good: the codimension of $\Bbb S^2 \hookrightarrow \Bbb S^3$ is one, and not two, so only one normal field will matter. It should be reasonably clear that the constant field $e_4$ is normal to $\Bbb S^2$ along $\Bbb S^3$, but tangent to $\Bbb S^3$. This means that the second fundamental form of $\Bbb S^2 \hookrightarrow \Bbb S^3$ has the form $\alpha \otimes e_4$ for some symmetric $2$-tensor $\alpha$. The goal is to show that $\alpha$ is traceless.

Comment: @IvoTerek but $\mathbb{S}^3$ is embedded by hyperspherical coordinates into $\mathbb{R}^4$, since that I think I need two normal vectors.

Comment: @DenisD.Bavrin You can also embed $S^3$ into $\Bbb R^{42}$ if you want, but there is no need to compute $40$ distinct normal vectors to understand the embedding $S^2 \to S^3$.

Comment: What techniques do you know to calculate the second fundamental form?